# How to remove Insufficient Privileges Errors in permission sets

Tags: soql, permissions

I can see number of permission sets created in the org through SOQL. but Could not see because of Insufficient Privileges Errors.
please suggest how can I see?

Answer (score 3):

To Manage permission sets, you need following user permissions.
**"Manage Profiles and Permission Sets".** You can go to your profile and edit this permission or you can ask your System Administrator to do this.

Also check the list view by click on edit and see if it is filtering anything.

You may not see each and every permission set in the UI as some permission sets belong to a profile. You can filter them via `IsOwnedByProfile` field on PermissionSet Object. The permission sets where this field is true will not show up. [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html)

Comment: Thanks Manjit for the reply..But I can see this Manage Profiles and Permission Sets already enabled. STill can't see all the permission sets in the org

Comment: Can you check the list view if it filters anything and updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Manjit..What is the way to disable permission ?

Comment: Which Permission do you want to disable?

Comment: I want to hide my permission set from other users.

Comment: I do not believe that you can do that. If they have "Manage Profiles and Permission" they can see all permission sets. Probably you can have delegated administration in place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51223/discussion-between-oookkk-and-manjit-singh).